# pip install BeautifulSoup nothing happens

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup4 and having trouble with pip. I have installed pip but when I go to run pip install BeautifulSoup nothing happens. Just a new line comes up on CMD

e.g.

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install BeautifulSoup

C:\Python27\Scripts>

Anyone have any ideas? This is Windows 7 btw. May well be something obvious I'm missing as I'm really new to Python.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I should also add that when I then try from bs4 import BeautifulSoup I get the following error:-
ImportError: No module named bs4

Comment: Try running as admin?

Comment: No, still nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: Try adding the `--verbose` option to get more output and see if it gives any more insight: `pip install --verbose BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Maybe pip is not installed?

Comment: You probably also have something else going on, but `BeautifulSoup` is not the same as `beautifulsoup4`. If you do `pip install BeautifulSoup`, you will not be able to do `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. You need to use `pip install beautifulsoup4` instead.

Comment: Hmm, still nothing when I use --verbose.
Pretty sure pip is installed, when i run get-pip.py I get the following:
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
Justin Barber - Thanks, but I get the same problem with that too.

Comment: What happens if you run `pip install -U pip --verbose`? And `pip install -U beautifulsoup4 --verbose` What do you see if you run: `python -m bs4` (what is the error message?)

Comment: If I run pip install -U pip --verbose the same thing happens (no output). If I run python -m bs4 it just says No module named bs4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these troubleshooting steps

1.Be sure you've followed all of [these](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) instructions carefully.

2.Check your path environmental variables to make sure you can run python from the command line.

3.Check your python **DIRECTORY** for the **SCRIPTS** folder.  Look there to see if pip is there.  I'm not 100 percent for sure but I think you must have pip here for it to be able to run from the command line.

By the way:

4.If you have python 3.4 or later, pip may already be installed.

if all else fails....

5.download [this](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and run this in an admin cmd window:

```
    python get-pip.py
```

6.try running the update commands if nothing else has worked.

```
    pip install -U setuptools
```

7.er....switch to easy_install

Comment: Tried all this and the problem persists (easy_install fails as well. when I use --verbose the execution terminates after printing 'Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org'. Not sure what I am doing wrong.