# pip install does nothing when executed in CMD

Tags: python

I have a problem just like the one in this thread:

[pip install BeautifulSoup nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231941/pip-install-beautifulsoup-nothing-happens)

I saw the solution to the post and figured that I didn't need to worry about whether or not I installed pip correctly since later versions of Python come with pip (I installed python only a few weeks ago). I also tried downloading get-pip.py and running it in the CMD like the solution said and it says the python is not recognized as an internal or external command etc. I'm assuming it's because there might be something wrong with my environment path variable?

Currently it is: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\scripts

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Try adding c:\Python27 at the end of the PATH variable.

Comment: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\scripts;c:\Python27 ?
Wouldn't that just be repeating?

EDIT: just tried it, didn't work

Comment: You only had the scripts folder in the path before, so you would be able to execute pip. But presumably pip requires python to be on the path as well, and the python executable is in c:\python27 - and your error message suggests that python is not on the path. if you open a command prompt and type `python`, does it work?

Comment: nope, double checked all the paths to make sure they were right. Still won't work.

Comment: So you haven't been able to run python at all? type `PATH` on the command line - does it include C:\Python27 at the end? You can also try `cd c:\python27` and then typing `python` to confirm that your installation has worked.

Comment: I can run python from IDLE. PATH returns with C:\Python27 at the end. I've also confirmed the installation worked.

Comment: So it works in the `C:\python27` folder, but you still cannot type `python` from another folder at the command prompt and get the REPL? Just a 'program not found' type error?

Comment: No I can type python in the CMD anywhere and get the version info and etc (I'm assuming this is the REPL). I just can't install packages. Whenever I run: pip install (package name), it just pauses for 5 seconds and starts a new line in the CMD waiting for another input from me like nothing happened. I've tried different packages and they all do the same thing. I tried moving the packages into different folders and that didn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: Try installing pip from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip). Beyond that I don't really know unfortunately.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. However, after trying to do all of this on a different computer and achieving relative success (I actually can get some packages to sort-of install), I'm really thinking the path variable is what's causing the screw up. On my primary computer the windows path variable is extremely saturated so I'm in the process of figuring out how to hard reset it - as it isn't as simple as just copy and pasting a new path. I'll try to update if possible so I can solve this problem for anyone else having the problem in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try to turn off your firewall. (At least it helped in my case when I faced similar problem).